# How to Call this Generic Method with a Generic Type?

Tags: c#, generics

I have this code at the moment:

```
Method1<Class1<Class2>>();

public void Method1<T>()
{
    // process
}
```

`Class1` needs a generic type itself (`Class2`).

I have to call the `Method1` about 10 times for all of which `Class2` would be the same type.

So how could I call `Method1` with something like following:

```
Method1<Class1<J>>();
```

Where `J` is a generic type itself for the `Class1`.

Comment: I’ve formatted the question (incidentally: you’ve already asked your fair share of questions here. Please do take the time to learn how to format properly!) but it’s still not understandable: (1) what language are you using? (2) what are you asking?

Comment: Can you please reword your question? I'm having a hard time trying to understand what you're asking.

Comment: Maybe you can add some information about your intent, so the answers will concentrate on the right direction. Do you want to get cleaner code for maintenance, shorter lines, try to avoid the double generics (also a static CA warning, for resolution see my answer below for this) etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `using` directive in your class file to alias either one or both of your classes.

```
using J = Class2;
using MyClass = Class1<Class2>;
```

(Apply appropriate namespaces as necessary to the class names, like `Foo.Bar.Class1`, etc.)

Now you can invoke your method with any of the following statements

```
Method1<Class1<Class2>>();
Method1<Class1<J>>();
Method1<MyClass>();
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes.

The same applies here:

```
IList<IEnumerable<string>>
```

Answer (score 0):

Or even cleaner code as using `using`: create a real subclass:

```
class SpecializedClass1:Class1<Class2>
{
    /* empty or do whatever makes sense in this specialized variant */
}
```